# CFML RegEx - I need to extract a pattern of aplh-number-number-number-number-number from a list

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a list;

```
D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0
```

I need to extract each of the 5 items.  Since there are no delimiters, I thought I would try RegEx.  But, I don't understand how to string 6 patterns together.

Comment: Can you please use pastebin or a gist to show us the original form? Or is your data really in that form with no line breaks?

Comment: That's what it looks like. No line breaks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option...

If the general pattern is consistent but the number part variable, you can split on the space before a name, e.g.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="input">D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0</cfsavecontent>

<cfset matches = input.split(' (?=[A-Z]\.)') />

<cfdump var=#matches# />
```

The `(?=`..`)` part is a lookahead, which confirms the sub-pattern within it matches at that position, but does not include it as part of the actual matched text. (So in this instance, only the space is used as the split delimiter.)

Also, as pointed out by Adam in the comments to Ray's answer, a space matches only the literal space character -  `chr(32)` - if you want to allow *any* whitespace (spaces,tabs,newlines,etc) then use `\s` instead.

Comment: <cfset results = reFindAll(pattern, mypdf, 2) />
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(results.pos)#">
    <cfoutput>match #i#: #Mid(mypdf, results.pos[i], results.len[i])#<br></cfoutput>
 <cfset RushingList = REReplace("#Mid(mypdf, results.pos[i], results.len[i])#","[0-9/]","","ALL")>
    </cfloop>

<cfsavecontent variable="input">D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0</cfsavecontent>
<cfset matches = RushingList.split(' (?=[A-Z]\.)') />  
    Works using your savecontent but not my data.

Comment: I get   D.Murray . (that's a space after the name then a decimal point)

Comment: That's probably because you've got a rereplace removing digits and slashes. **[Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12449540/edit)** with exact versions of your current code and the contents of the `mypdf` variable.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming my comment above is ok, this worked ok for me.

```
<cfset input = "D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0">

<cfset pattern = "[a-zA-Z\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+">
<cfset matches = reMatch(pattern,input)>

<cfdump var="#matches#">
```

Comment: <cfset pattern = '(?i)Rushing ATT YDS AVG LG TD RUSHING ATT YDS AVG LG TD (.+?)(\Total)' />
<cfset results = reFindAll(pattern, mypdf, 2) />
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(results.pos)#">
    <cfoutput>match #i#: #Mid(mypdf, results.pos[i], results.len[i])#<br></cfoutput>
 <cfset RushingList = REReplace("#Mid(mypdf, results.pos[i], results.len[i])#","[0-9/]","","ALL")>
</cfloop>
<cfset pattern = "[a-zA-Z\.]+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ ">
<cfset pattern = "[a-zA-Z\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+ [\d\.]+">
<cfset matches = reMatch(#pattern#,#RushingList#)>

<cfdump var="#matches#">

Comment: @raymond-camden: you might wanna use/suggest \s instead of a hard-coded space, just in case in the original data they're not space characters.

Comment: <cfset results = reFindAll(pattern, mypdf, 2) />
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(results.pos)#">
    <cfoutput>match #i#: #Mid(mypdf, results.pos[i], results.len[i])#<br></cfoutput>
 <cfset RushingList = REReplace("#Mid(mypdf, results.pos[i], results.len[i])#","[0-9/]","","ALL")>
</cfloop>
<cfset pattern = "[a-zA-Z\.]+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ ">
<cfset pattern = "[a-zA-Z\.]+ [\d]+ [\d]+ [\d\.]+ [\d]+ [\d]+ ">
<cfset matches = reMatch("#pattern#","#RushingList#")>
<cfoutput>#pattern#</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#matches#">
<cfabort>

Comment: <cfset pattern = "[a-zA-Z\.]+[\s\d]+[\s\d]+[\s\d\.]+[\s\d]+[\s\d]"> gives me 
array
1  D.Murray .
2  A.Bradshaw .
3  T.Romo .
4  D.Wilson .
5  L.Vickers .
But none of the numbers return.

Comment: user990016 post the code you're trying into your question, prefixed by either a tab or four spaces, and it will be significantly easier to read.

Comment: Ray, inside character classes `.` is literal - i.e. `[\d\.]+` is simplified to `[\d.]+`

Comment: user9900116, I'd ditto Peter. My code worked fine for me so it must be the input that is different.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the resulting data in an array of space delimited lists?

```
<cfscript>
var data = "D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0";

// inject "|" between each set of 6 variables
var dataPipeList = data.replaceAll('(([^ ]+ ){5}[^ ]+) ','$1|');

// now convert your piped list into an array of space delimited strings
var dataArray = listToArray(dataPipeList,'|');

// eg.
dataArray == [
    'D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0',
    'A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1',
    'T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0',
    'D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0',
    'L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0'
]
</cfscript>
```

Or do you want an array of arrays?

```
<cfscript>
var data = "D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0";

// split into an array at every space
var temp = listToArray(data,' ');

// loop the array in steps of 6, adding each to a new array
var dataArray = [];
for ( var i = 1; i <= arrayLen( temp ); i = i + 6 ) {
    arrayAppend( dataArray, [
        temp[i],
        temp[i+1],
        temp[i+2],
        temp[i+3],
        temp[i+4],
        temp[i+5]
    ] );
}

// eg.
dataArray == [
    [ 'D.Murray', '20', '131', '6.6', '48', '0' ],
    [ 'A.Bradshaw', '17', '78', '4.6', '33', '1',
    [ 'T.Romo', '5', '12', '2.4', '9', '0' ],
    [ 'D.Wilson', '2', '4', '2.0', '3', '0' ],
    [ 'L.Vickers', '1', '0', '0.0', '0', '0' ]
]
</cfscript>
```

You can even use the Java regex Pattern class to produce an array of arrays, like so:

```
<cfscript>
var data = "D.Murray 20 131 6.6 48 0 A.Bradshaw 17 78 4.6 33 1 T.Romo 5 12 2.4 9 0 D.Wilson 2 4 2.0 3 0 L.Vickers 1 0 0.0 0 0";

// build a regex pattern
var regex = '([a-zA-Z.]+) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+)';
var pattern = createObject('java','java.util.regex.Pattern').compile(regex);

// get a matcher for the data
var matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

// build an array from the matched strings
var dataArray = [];
while ( matcher.find() ) {
    arrayAppend( dataArray, [
        matcher.group(1),
        matcher.group(2),
        matcher.group(3),
        matcher.group(4),
        matcher.group(5),
        matcher.group(6)
] );
}

// eg.
dataArray == [
    [ 'D.Murray', '20', '131', '6.6', '48', '0' ],
    [ 'A.Bradshaw', '17', '78', '4.6', '33', '1',
    [ 'T.Romo', '5', '12', '2.4', '9', '0' ],
    [ 'D.Wilson', '2', '4', '2.0', '3', '0' ],
    [ 'L.Vickers', '1', '0', '0.0', '0', '0' ]
]
</cfscript>
```